# Python why this if statement returns True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I am wondering why it returns True:

```
if False or True and True == True and (False == True or False == (not True)) or False and False and True:
    pass
```

doesn't it accept "and False" part in the end as False?
doesn't all statements with "and" return True?

Comment: does code above equals to: if False or True and True == True and (False == True or False == (not True)) or (False and False and True):

Comment: The order of operations is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). From here it is a matter of applying the rules mechanically.

Comment: "doesn't all statements with "and" return True?" Why would they? Did you try just `False and True` by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with:

```
False or True and True == True and (False == True or False == (not True)) or False and False and True
```

Solve parentheses first:

```
(False == True or False == (not True))
```

Solve parentheses first - `not True` is `False`:

```
(False == True or False == False)
```

Next order of operation: `==`:

```
((False == True) or (False == False))
```

Resulting in:

```
((False) or (True))
```

Next order of operation: `or`:

```
(True)
```

Now we have:

```
False or True and True == True and (True) or False and False and True
```

Next order of operation: `==`:

```
False or True and (True == True) and True or False and False and True
```

Resulting in:

```
False or True and (True) and True or False and False and True
```

Next order of operation: `and`:

```
False or ((True and True) and True) or ((False and False) and True)
```

Resulting in:

```
False or ((True) and True) or ((False) and True)
```

And then:

```
False or (True) or (False)
```

Now the `or` operator:

```
((False or True) or False)
```

And then:

```
((True) or False)
```

Which results in `True` because `True or False` is `True`.